# Spring and WSO2 Identity Server - SCIM2.0 API for User CRUD

Tags: java, spring-boot, wso2, wso2-identity-server, scim2

I'm implementing an application with Spring Boot. From the application some users will have the permission to create, update, delete other users. To do so I'm using WSO2 Idenity server SCIM 2.0 APIs.

When I try with postman to call for example this api: POST localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/scim2/Users

to create a new user and i pass all the required information:

1. Access token, generated with the command:

   curl -L -X POST 'localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/oauth2/token' -H 'Authorization: Basic clientid:clientsecret' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' --data-urlencode 'username=manager' --data-urlencode 'password=manager' --data-urlencode 'scope=internal_user_mgt_create'
2. clientid
3. clientsecret
4. scope (internal_user_mgt_create)

it works, but now I have to implement it in java.

So I created a UserController and I implemented this:

```
@PostMapping("https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/scim2/Users")
public ResponseEntity<Void> createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserRequest createUserRequest) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    
    String plainCreds = clientId:clientSecret;
    byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
    byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
    String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return ...;
}
```

how do I specify in the header these other things:

```
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' 
--data-urlencode 'username=manager' 
--data-urlencode 'password=manager' 
--data-urlencode 'scope=internal_user_mgt_create'
```

Answer (score 1):

The values that you have mentioned are for the token call right? In that case these does not need to be in the header of the request. You should have them as the request body.

Once you get the token from the `oauth2/token` you can use it to invoke the SCIM APIs. Following is a sample API call to invoke user creation with a bearer token.

```
curl -L -X POST 'https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer 15b93905-68b2-3377-b77b-9bd1968d7ff9' --data-raw '{
    "schemas": [],
    "userName": "somindaRest",
    "password": "somindaRest"
}
```